# 'SSL connection is required' error when connecting to Azure MySQL database in R

Tags: mysql, r, azure, rstudio

When I try to run the following code (credentials omitted) in R which connects to an Azure MySQL database, I receive an SSL error:

```
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                 dbname = dbname,
                 host = host,
                 port = port,
                 user = user,
                 password = password)
```

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
  Failed to connect to database: Error: SSL connection is required. Please specify SSL options and retry.
```

I'm able to connect to the database from my IP on MySQL Workbench.

If I disable the SSL requirements on Azure, the error disappears. I've attempted using the RMariaDB connector as well as adding `sslmode = 'require'` with no luck.

What's particularly strange about this error is the above code snippet works completely fine when I run it in RStudio Cloud. However, it doesn't work when I run it on my local RStudio or RGui session. I've attempted it on another computer and I get the same error, only RStudio Cloud seems to work.

Here's my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] DBI_1.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.3 tools_3.6.3    RMySQL_0.10.20 packrat_0.5.0
```

Comment: do you get a different error with sslmode=require?

Comment: Nope, the error is identical